# Can someone explain what they are doing at the sum part of this question

Tags: r, function, for-loop, vector

Was looking at some questions online and this was the question

Create the function unique, which given a vector will return a new vector with the elements of the first vector with duplicated elements removed.

I looked at the solution and this is what they had

```
f.uniq <- function (v) {
  s <- c()

  for(i in 1:length(v)) {
    if(sum(v[i] == s) == 0) {
      s <- c(s, v[i])
    }
  }
  s
}
f.uniq(c(9, 9, 1, 1, 1, 0))
```

if anyone could explain what is happening here

```
if(sum(v[i] == s) == 0)
```

Comment: It might help to break it apart piece-by-piece: what does `v[i] == s` do? what does `sum(v[i] == s)` do? what does `sum(v[i] == s) == 0` do?

Comment: How many times an element in vector v in position i appears in vector s. The loop appends values from vector v to empty vector s one by one until it finds a duplicate

Comment: I understand the ```v[I] == s``` and I kind of understand the ```sum```, but the ```== 0``` I cant grasp

Comment: You only want to append the values that are not yet present in the vector. So in order to append a number, the amount values that are equal to the one you are checking int the current iteration of the loop has to be 0.

Answer (score 1):

The code `v[i] == s` Performs elementwise comparison between `v[i]` and all elements of `s`. `v[i] == s` returns a list like `TRUE TRUE FALSE` for example. If the sum of this is larger than 0, this means that the element `v[i]` is already contained in the list. Otherwise it is appended.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow and thanks for your answer.  Feel free to add some output results to show exactly what you mean. For instance there is never `TRUE TRUE FALSE` in the example of the original post.

Answer (score 1):

`sum(v[i] == s) == 0` indicates the condition that `v[i]` is not in `s`. Here, `v[i] == s` yields a logic vector of same dimension as `s`, so `sum(v[i] == s)` counts the number of `TRUE`s there. If there is no `TRUE` i.e., `sum(v[i] == s) == 0`, then you can enter the `if` statement.

Comment: It might be helpful to note that `any(v[i] == s)` is a more concise way of expressing the same concept

Answer (score 0):

Some `cat` might be useful in this kind of situation

```
f.uniq <- function (v) {
  s <- c()

  for(i in 1:length(v)) {
      cat("\ni=",i,"\nv[i] ==s :", v[i] == s,"\nsum(v[i] == s):",sum(v[i] == s),"\n")
    if(sum(v[i] == s) == 0) {
      s <- c(s, v[i])
    }
  }
  s
}

## > f.uniq(c(9, 9, 1, 1, 1, 0))

## i= 1 
## v[i] ==s :  
## sum(v[i] == s): 0 

## i= 2 
## v[i] ==s : TRUE 
## sum(v[i] == s): 1 

## i= 3 
## v[i] ==s : FALSE 
## sum(v[i] == s): 0 

## i= 4 
## v[i] ==s : FALSE TRUE 
## sum(v[i] == s): 1 

## i= 5 
## v[i] ==s : FALSE TRUE 
## sum(v[i] == s): 1 

## i= 6 
## v[i] ==s : FALSE FALSE 
## sum(v[i] == s): 0 
## [1] 9 1 0
```